# c# More elegant way to assign array to a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listcontrol

I have this:

```
// Load changelog types
ChangeLogType[] Types = ChangeLogFunctions.GetAllChangelogTypes();
foreach(ChangeLogType Rec in Types){
    ListItem N = new ListItem();
    N.Text = Rec.Type;
    N.Value = Rec.ID.ToString();
    LstChangeLogType.Items.Add(N);
}
```

It calls a function that returns an array of ChangeLogTypes, and then adds each one into a list control.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this?  I feel I'm repeating code each time I do this or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, LINQ to Objects is your friend:

```
var changeLogTypes = ChangeLogFunctions.GetAllChangelogTypes()
                                       .Select(x => new ListItem { 
                                                      Text = x.Type,
                                                      Value = x.ID.ToString() })
                                       .ToList();
```

The `Select` part is projecting each `ChangeLogType` to a `ListItem`, and `ToList()` converts the resulting sequence into a `List<ListItem>`.

This is assuming you really wanted a *new* list with all these entries. If you need to add the results to an *existing* list, you'd do that without the `ToList` call, but calling `AddRange` on an existing list with the result of the `Select` call.

It's well worth learning more about LINQ in general and LINQ to Objects in particular - it can make all kinds of things like this much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;

var items = Types
  .Select (rec => ListItem
    {
      Text = Rec.Type;
      Value = Rec.ID.ToString();
    }

LstChangeLogType.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: The => lambda expression uses an object Initializer to give values to the ListItem.  The items are actually created when AddRange is called, as AddRange does its foreach.

Answer (score 2):

```
var range = Types.Select(rec => 
       new ListItem { Text = rec.Type, Value = rec.ID.ToString() });

LstChangeLogType.AddRange(range);
```

Answer (score 2):

Linq?

```
LstChangeLogType.Items = Types.Select(x => new ListItem() 
                     { Text = x.Type, Value = x.ID.ToString() }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using some LINQ extension methods:

```
LstChangeLogType.AddItems.AddRange(
    Types.Select(t => 
        new ListItem() { Text = t.Type, Value = t.ID.ToString() }).ToArray());
```

Comment: No need for the `.ToArray()` I think.

Comment: @Henk - Depends if `.Items` =  `ListItemCollection`, as it is built on `IList` not `IList<ListItem>`, so doesn't have the `AddRange(IEnumerable<ListItem>)` overload.